# javascript wait until variable is set

Tags: javascript, promise

Can you make a function wait until a variable is set by another function? This is my example:

```
function setvar(){
 //some process that may take a while
 myvar = 'value';
}

const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(myvar);
});

promise1.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

this doesnt seem to work, the function begins even if the variable is not ready. What should I do? I dont want settimeout or setinterval because I dont know exactly how long it is going to take each time.

Comment: what's the purpose of `setvar` function that you never call? - it should return a promise then all would be good - then you don't need `promise1` ... just `setvar().then(console.log)`

Comment: Fix the `setvar` function so that it takes a callback or returns a Promise, then you can chain off of it easily

Comment: setvar is called on page load but even if setvar finishes its execution it is no guarantee that the variable is going to be set by then.

Comment: You need `setVar` (or whatever it is calling it) to call a callback or `resolve()` a promise. Pass the `'value'` as an argument. Do **not** set a global variable.

Comment: thank you but as I said, resolving the function doesnt mean the variable gets set on time for the other function to execute since the variable gets its values from a webpage and between the time it takes to load and then too populate there is not enough time.

Comment: This is a duplicate in the way "How do I bake cupcakes?" is a duplicate of "How do I use an oven?".

Answer (score 1):

In the promise you'll need create a loop that would check if variable was set:

```js
var myvar;
function setvar(){
 //some process that may take a while
 myvar = 'value';
}

const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const loop = () => myvar !== undefined ? resolve(myvar) : setTimeout(loop)
  loop();
});

promise1.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});


setTimeout(setvar, 2000);
```

Comment: cant be done without settimeout?

Comment: Not unless function that changes the variable returns a promise

Comment: cant I make it so it returns the variable as a promise?

Comment: is variable global? or do you have access to the function that sets the variable?

Comment: yes, the variable is declared globally as an empty array and then on load setvar() fills it up.

Comment: TypeScript async/await: `export const waitForValue = async (context: any, property: string) => await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const loop = () => context[property] !== undefined ? resolve(context[property]) : setTimeout(loop, 100)
  loop()
})
   // await waitForValue(this, 'wallpaperDirectory')`